# Pythonでrequestsを使用してログインしたい。

Tags: python, html, python3, cookie, session

PinterestというwebサイトにPythonを使用しログインまでできたのですが、セッションが上手く保たれていないのか。実行したいことまで上手く行きません。

**やりたいこと**
https://www.pinterest.jp/r/pin/554505772869102844/4995915543595742901/ab9290928e62760b540f32156fb9686925897abcbda51275fe2866dd3442d330
このURLにアクセスするとリダイレクトされて下記のURLに飛びます。
https://www.behance.net/gallery/67141435/X-O-Highlight-Messenger
このURLをrequestsの`.url`で取得したいのですが、Pinterestにログインなしでアクセスするとリダイレクトされない仕様になっています。

なので下記のコードでログインまで行きました。

```
import requests


ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'

headers = {'User-Agent': ua}


payload = {'username_or_email':'xxxxx@mail.com', 'password':'xxxxxxxxx'}
login_url = 'https://accounts.pinterest.com/v3/login/handshake/'

def login(login_url, payload):
    s = requests.Session()
    p = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    r = s.get('https://www.pinterest.jp/r/pin/554505772869102844/4995915543595742901/ab9290928e62760b540f32156fb9686925897abcbda51275fe2866dd3442d330')
    print(p.status_code)
    print(r.url)

login(login_url, payload)
```

status_codeは200とログインはできているようです。

**助けて頂きたい事**
　ここで問題にはまっています。一度、ブラウザ側でアクセスした後このプログラムを実行すると上手くリダイレクト先のURLを取得できます。
　しかし、しばらく時間を置くとプログラムからログインはできてもリダイレクトされません。
毎回、ブラウザでログイン後にプログラムを走らせるのは手間が掛かるのでプログラムのみで動作させたいです。

**最後に**
cookieを付与して（返ってきたcookieをそのまま返す？）アクセスしてみたり、色々やってみましたがもうわかりません。
ブラウザに保存される何かをサーバに送り返してセッションか何かを保った状態をキープしないといけないと考えているのですが、何かわかりません。デベロッパーツールのNetworkを見たりして見たのですが、どこに注目してよいのか分かりません。
なので質問させて頂きます。
seleniumはできる限り使用したくないです。
贅沢いって申し訳ありません。
ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 手元で実行してみたところ、ランダム？にリダイレクトされている印象です。（ブラウザでの挙動は関係なさそうです）

Comment: というと何度も繰り返せばリダイレクトできるという事でしょうか？ごめんなさい知識不足です。

Comment: 先程、試しに`login`の最後で`return r.url == 対象URL` して `result = [login(login_url, payload) for _ in range(100)]; print(result.count(True))` としてみたところ、20回の試行中15回リダイレクトされていました。また、リダイレクトされている場合は404が返っているようです。

Comment: この辺りはPinterestの仕様次第なので、なんともいえないです。 / ところで、Pinterest APIを利用するというのはいかがでしょうか？ [Pinterest Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: 20回関数をfor文で試したところ確かに2回だけリダイレクトされました。ただstatusコードはどれも200です。このURLがAPIを使用して取得したものでそこからリダイレクト先のURLが欲しくこのような事をしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

だいぶ愚直な手段になりますが、ログインした後にリダイレクトが発生するまで取得し続けるというのはいかがでしょうか。

```
from time import sleep
import requests

target_url = 'https://www.pinterest.jp/r/pin/554505772869102844/4995915543595742901/ab9290928e62760b540f32156fb9686925897abcbda51275fe2866dd3442d330'


def login():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = requests.get(target_url)
        while r.url == target_url:
            print(".", end="")
            sleep(0.5)
            r = requests.get(target_url)
    return r.url


def main():
    print(login())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: それしかないですよね。コードありがとうございます。私の環境だと成功率が低く全然アクセスできません。なぜブラウザですっと上手く行くのにプログラムだとこうも上手くいかないのでしょう。困りました。

Comment: やはりseleniumを使用するしかなさそうです。

Comment: 残念です。ちなみに、こちらの環境ではログイン処理は不要でした（ `payload` 、 `login_url` なしでリダイレクト先の取得ができました）。

Comment: そうだったんですね。ログインしていないブラウザでアクセスすると404が返されるので、てっきりログイン必須だと考えていました。もう少しrequestsで考えてみます！

Comment: ログインしてないブラウザだとアクセスできない気がします。プログラムからログイン不要での成功率はどれぐらいでしょうか？

Comment: サンプルコードを編集しました。これで現状3回〜10回程度でリダイレクト先を取得出来ているようです。

Comment: すごいです。精度上がりました！なぜこれ'print(".", end="")'を挟むだけで精度が変わると思い付いたのですか？withってこのような使い方も出来るのですね。ファイルに書き込む時にしか使わないかと考えていました。

Comment: > `print` これは先程のコードをリファクタリングしただけですので、内容は変わっていません。 > `with` `requests.Session` ではこのように指定することで自動的にセッションを終了時にクローズすることができます。

Comment: そうなのですね。てっきりこれを挟むとうまくいくのかと思いました。何からなにまでありがとうござます。