# 404ページのURLをPython requestsで取得したい。

Tags: python, python3, python-requests

Pythonのrequestsを使用しページのURLを取得したいのですが、普通のページでなくリダイレクト先のページで404のステータスコードがでるページです。

以下のURLにgetを何回かループで投げると下記ののURLがリダイレクト先として取得できます。
　詳しい内容、[ここで](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53665/python%E3%81%A7requests%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)質問しています。
https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/554505772848816821/4995915543595742901/51a16eafabbb128c3c57b4a5087421b7a031e52bcbc41b26a4cb756137b347a6

**問題**
しかし、下記のURLはリンクが切れていてrequestsでgetを投げるとエラーになりプログラムが停まってしまいます。`r.url`でリダイレクト先のURLを取得しようと考えたのですが、上手くいきません。
エラーの内容にリダイレクト先URLが含まれているのでプログラムの変数内にURLがあることは伺えます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f49a6e75358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.behance.netgallery', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Portfolio/23252259 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f49a6e75358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlget.py", line 55, in <module>
    got_url = get_redirect()
  File "urlget.py", line 31, in get_redirect
    r = requests.get(target_url)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 524, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 659, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 659, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 238, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.behance.netgallery', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Portfolio/23252259 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f49a6e75358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

それを取り出す方法をご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

**教えて頂きたい事**
https://www.behance.netgallery/Portfolio/23252259
このURLを取り出したい。

追記
回答ありがとうございます。

しかし、回答のコードを実行すると以下のエラーが出力されます。
正規表現のreをimportしろという事かと考え実行してみたのですが、ダメでした。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "others2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/twitter/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 37, in <module>
    cookie_re = re.compile(r'^[ \t\f]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-\w.]+)', re.ASCII)
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

Comment: 追記はプログラムの問題というより、環境の問題ではないかと思います。

Comment: エラー自体は`re`に存在しない`compile`を呼び出している、というエラーです。`re`を正しくimportできていないのではないでしょうか。たとえば標準ライブラリ以外に、`re.py`というファイルを作っていたりしませんか？

Comment: 正規表現の勉強をしようと思って作成したファイルが原因でした。上手く動きました。本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決したいことは以下なのではと思います。

- `requests.get()`を使って特定のURLにリクエストし、リダイレクト先のURLを取得したい。
- しかし、リダイレクト先がリンクの切れの場合、例外が発生する
- 例外が発生したときにもリダイレクト先のURLを取得したい。

例えば、`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`を`except`で処理するのはどうですか？以下は、質問で参照している[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53665/python%E3%81%A7requests%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)の [PicoSushi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/29826/picosushi)さんの回答の`login()`に手を加えたものです。

```
from time import sleep
import requests

def login(target_url):

  try :
    r = requests.get(target_url)
    while r.url == target_url:
      print(".", end="")
      sleep(0.5)
      r = requests.get(target_url)  
    url = r.url

  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    url = e.request.url

  return url
```